# Bought a 256 GB micro SD Card for only $28 on Aliexpress, my tests show its not fake, how can I be completely sure?

Tags: sd-card, dd

I bought a 256 GB SD Card from [AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33028535336.html) for around $28 and at first assumed it was junk but the reviews seemed to be good.

[image]

I used f3write and f3read to verify it does contain 256GB, and showed an average speed of 60 MB/s.

The result from black disk magic show:

[image]

I am wondering why it was priced so cheaply and what other tests I might do? Could it be it supports none of the other formats? Is there any way it could get around f3write? Generally, what gives here?

Comment: Just thinking: If a cheap copy provides anything a brand product does - what makes it a "cheap copy", except the price? You got yourself something from a not-so-big manufacturer from one of the cheapest marketplaces out there and wonder what could be wrong? :) - reliability might not be equal to others, transfer speed seems lower than the ones i know from bigger brands, products like this might not really be certified or using defined standards, some say they could come with pre-installed malware... lot of things are possible, including that you got a working product!

Comment: In the UK you can get an Integral brand 256GB micro SD for £28, which is about $33. $28 doesn't seem that wrong for an even more off name product that could still be legitimate. Even Sandisk aren't *that* much more expensive at that price point at the moment. Chances are you just got a cheap bulk no-name but legitimate product, they do exist. It's the 1TB cards at $50, about 1/10th the price of a legitimate card, that would be most likely to be fake.

Comment: It is most likely legit. I have purchased 256gb flash drive for $35 almost 2 years ago - works without any issues

Comment: I purchased a 512 GB for less than $30 from Amazon.  Only reason it would be fake is due to the brand being generic and the seller quality controls from AliExpress.  Even if it’s real you only have a generic product so it’s performance likely is extremely poor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just because a program says that a SD card has 256GB it doesn't mean that it has all that storage. Flash drives/MicroSD card can have its firmware modified so it shows a capacity that is not real. You can check on Amazon that 256GB MicroSD cards are at [similar prices](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=256gb+micro+sd+card&crid=1Y6J46FMDI0EH&sprefix=256gb+micr%2Caps%2C274&ref=nb_sb_ss_i_1_10) from reputable brands as what you bought.

Looking through some reviews, some people did this test below and no issues there. You might have got a legitimate card with a slightly lower price in cost for reliability, warranty, etc.

In order to test a flash drive I use the program [H2testw](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/download/did/77/) that:

> H2testw works by writing large 1GB files to the free space and then reading them back. If the read data isn’t the same as what was written, there’s a possible issue. 
>   [Source](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/test-and-detect-fake-or-counterfeit-usb-flash-drives-bought-from-ebay-with-h2testw/).

This test can take a few hours to complete depending on what size you wanna test. I would suggest that a 32GB test would be good enough to check if there's any issue.